# Question About YQL

Tags: image, load, yql

I don't know YQL can load image in html content and output it ?. I view more tut about YQL but dont see anything about it.

Comment: Can you expand on the question a little, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Yeah. I want get image link form rss or html content and show image

Comment: All RSS/HTML on the internet, or do you have some particular source(s) in mind?

Answer (score 0):

YQL is just a tool to fetch information, either in XML or JSON format. It's up to you to parse the information. If you have an RSS feed, you would have to parse out the image URL and display the image in a web page using the `img` tag.